How to add a new condition (if) to the back button?
I try to add a new condition (if) to the back button in a plugin file.
The back button codes are in the render.php file.
    $back_url = '';
    if (!$modal) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['back'])) {
            $back_url = "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        } else {
            $back_url = "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $back_url = remove_query_arg(array('login', 'type'), $back_url);
        }
        $back_title = __('Go Back');
    }

So I changed these lines to the code I wrote below (but it doesn't work):
if (!$modal) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['back'])) {
        // Check if the user came from the checkout page
        $referer = wp_get_referer();
        $is_from_checkout = strpos($referer, '/checkout/') !== false;

        if ($is_from_checkout) {
            $back_url = "https://example.com/cart";
        } else {
            $back_url = "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        }

        $back_title = __('Go Back');
    } else {
        $back_url = "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $back_url = remove_query_arg(array('login', 'type'), $back_url);
        $back_title = __('Go Back');
    }
}

Can you check these codes and make the necessary changes, please?
That's why the back button doesn't work there. And for this reason, I want there to be a condition, that if it comes from the checkout page to the login page, the URL will return, not to the same page, but to the cart page. else, return to the same page.

I found the answer myself! Here is my last working code:
if (!$modal) {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    $is_from_checkout = strpos($referer, '/checkout/') !== false;

    if (isset($_REQUEST['back'])) {
        $back_url = $is_from_checkout ? home_url('/cart') : "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $back_url = remove_query_arg(array('login', 'type'), $back_url);
    } else {
        $back_url = $is_from_checkout ? home_url('/cart') : $referer;
    }

    $back_title = __('Go Back');
}


and I understood that There is no need to use the domain name when addressing. When home_url can be used.

